# Proof congruence identity modulo $p$: $2^2\cdot4^2\cdot\dots\cdot(p-3)^2\cdot(p-1)^2 \equiv (-1)^{\frac{1}{2}(p+1)}\mod{p}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, congruences, congruence-relations

I want to show that for every odd prime $p$ the following congruence holds:

$$
2^2\cdot4^2\cdot\dots\cdot(p-3)^2\cdot(p-1)^2 \equiv (-1)^{\frac{1}{2}(p+1)}\mod{p}
$$

How would I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If $k$ is even, then $p-k$ is odd. You can split each square into the product of two complementary terms to cover every nonzero residue class:

$$\begin{align} \prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} (2k)^2 &\equiv \prod_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} (-1) \cdot (2k) \cdot (p-2k) & \pmod p 
\\&= (-1)^{(p-1)/2} \prod_{n=1}^{p-1} n 
\\&= (-1)^{(p-1)/2} (p-1)!
\end{align}$$

and Wilson's theorem implies

$$ (p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p $$